# Occurrence of *critical* damping

Tags: condensed-matter, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation, fine-tuning

I am trying to understand the origin of some transient signals the vast majority of which have shape $(t/\tau) \exp(-t/\tau)$ for $t\gt 0$. This is notoriously the impulse response of a [critically damped harmonic oscillator](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticallyDampedSimpleHarmonicMotion.html).

Does anybody know of any physical oscillator, in condensed matter or other domains, that tends to be naturally critically damped?

Comment: One could argue that critically damped oscillators are everywhere... we just don't pay attention to them, because they do not oscillate. E.g., a chair or a car suspension.

Comment: Those are over-damped oscillators at large. Critically damped is when Q=1/2

Answer (score 1):

To cite the comments:

> Me: One could argue that critically damped oscillators are everywhere... we just don't pay attention to them, because they do not oscillate. E.g., a chair or a car suspension.
> OP: Those are over-damped oscillators at large. Critically damped is when Q=1/2

The nuance here is that *damped oscillations* and *overdamped oscillations* are two **regimes**, whereas *critically damped oscillations* is a **boundary** between them, which occurs at certain exact relation between parameters. This exact relation between parameters might occur occasionally, but it has not any specific value, besides the theoretical one - separating the two regimes.

One could argue that physics courses spend a lot of time on it precisely because it separates two regimes - just like in studying critical phenomena we are concerned with *phase boundaries* and behavior near them, rather than with what happens inside the phases (that is the difference is like studying a gas, studying a liquid and studying a transition between the two.)

Another likely reason why physics teacher emphasize this case is to illustrate how one handles ordinary linear differential equation with degenerate roots.